# Pro Spring 3book, class path resource [app-context-annotation.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring

I'm trying to learn Spring3 by following book Pro Spring3. I'm in chapter 4 where the author explains IoC and DI. He uses GenericXmlApplicationContext to specify the configuration file. He does the following:

```
package com.apress.prospring3.ch4;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class UsingSetterInjection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        //ctx.load("classpath:app-context-xml.xml");
        ctx.load("classpath:app-context-annotation.xml");
        ctx.refresh();      

        MessageRenderer messageRenderer = ctx.getBean("messageRenderer", MessageRenderer.class);
        messageRenderer.render();
    }
}
```

My structure is

src/main/resources/app-context-annotation.xml

IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context-annotation.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app-context-annotation.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Did you create a Spring configuration file named "app-context-xml.xml"? If so, make sure you've added it to the classpath of your application

Comment: My structure is 
src/main/resources/app-context-annotation.xml

Comment: First, learn to accept answer! Second, I bet you are using Maven.  Check if there is target/classes/app-context-annotation.xml.  If not, then you have not even compiled your code

Answer (score 1):

Give the complete path and it will work like a charm.

```
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following line to load your xml file?

```
ctx.load("classpath*:app-context-annotation.xml");
```

I have added a ***** after the classpath. I think this should resolve your problem. Otherwise you need to check whether this file is there in the application classpath or not.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you check the classes folder of your deployed application for this xml? If it is there in classes folder then there must be another problem.