# Eclipse Spring Dynamic web project classpath find xml config

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm new with Spring and Hibernate. I did a project from book Prospring4
But I did not a simple java application, but Dynamic web project (for future). I wrote all code and created a `app-context-annotation.xml` with beans. In book I have a code to load it:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml");
```

In my project I have a standart path - `WebContent/META-INF` and I add folder with file where. But always I get a error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context-annotation.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I read many forum answers but I really don't understand WHY it happens!
I tried to convert my project to Maven project, but got this error again.

PLZ tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT.
Ok. Now this is my project structure, but result is the same exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5CtG.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pro Spring 3book, class path resource \[app-context-annotation.xml\] cannot be opened because it does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971077/pro-spring-3book-class-path-resource-app-context-annotation-xml-cannot-be-ope)

Comment: No. 'Cos there is not DYnamic web project and I don't have those folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Webcontent folder on your classpath? I mean, when you build your project you see app-context-annotation.xml into the classes folder? If not you should add the Webcontent folder to the build path or move the xml to another folder. p.e: src/main/java

Comment: I edit the question. And what you mean - in my classpath - where I need to check it?